# Java server send html page from file to browser

Tags: java, html, file, bufferedreader, printwriter

I've been trying to make a java server that displays the index from a file. I'm creating a SocketServer and connecting it to a port. Then creating a Socket acting as the client and creating a PrintWriter connected to the client's socket outputstream. Everything works if I hardcode the page to the PrintWriter, but when I try to read a file line by line and send it to the PrintWriter, nothing gets displayed.

```
package com.github.masonnoyce;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class AServer
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        AServer server = new AServer();
        int portNumber = 8080;
        //create server socket and say that it is running
        final ServerSocket myServer = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        System.out.println("I have Connected To Port " + portNumber);

        boolean running = true;
        while(running)
        {
                //See if anyone connects
                try(Socket client = myServer.accept())
                {                    
                    server.sendPage(client);
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Something went wrong streaming the page");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
        }
        try
        {
            myServer.close();
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Server Is now closed");
        }        
    }
    private void sendPage(Socket client) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Page writter called");

        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());//Make a writer for the output stream to the client
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/to/index.html"));//grab a file and put it into the buffer
        String line = reader.readLine();//line to go line by line from file
        while(line != null)//repeat till the file is empty
        {
            printWriter.println(line);//print current line
            printWriter.flush();// I have also tried putting this outside the while loop right before 
            printWriter.close()
            line = reader.readLine();//read next line
        }
        reader.close();//close the reader
        printWriter.close();//Close the writer
//***********This section works if I replace the While loop With It**********//
//            printWriter.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
//            printWriter.println("Content-Type: text/html");
//            printWriter.println("\r\n");
//            printWriter.println("<p> Hello world </p>");
//            printWriter.flush();//needed to actually send the data to the client
//            printWriter.close();//Close the writer
//************Above is the Hardcoding I was talking about****************************// 
    }    
}
```

Now I know the server should be running on a thread, that it can never technically exit at the moment, and that some of the imports are not needed. I'm not worried about that right now. I just need to figure out why PrintWriter doesn't like to use a file when it comes to html being presented on a browser. I have created a debug PrintWriter that writes to a file to test if I have the right file location and it works with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you test your server with a web browser, you need to send a valid HTTP request including HTTP headers which are provided in your hardcoded part.

So, you should just add output of the header part just before you print the contents of the file.

Also you need to collect the information about the file size, and send `"Content-Length: " + file_size + "\r\n"` header.

There's a bug with closing printWriter before you finish reading the page file, you need to close it after the loop:

```
    while(line != null)//repeat till the file is empty
    {
        printWriter.println(line);//print current line
        printWriter.flush();// I have also tried putting this outside the while loop right before 
        printWriter.close() // BUG: no ";" and closing printWriter too early
        line = reader.readLine();//read next line
    }
```

So, updated method to send your file to the client is as follows:

```java
    private void sendPage(Socket client) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Page writter called");

        File index = new File("index.html");

        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());// Make a writer for the output stream to
                                                                            // the client
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(index));// grab a file and put it into the buffer
        // print HTTP headers
        printWriter.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        printWriter.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        printWriter.println("Content-Length: " + index.length());
        printWriter.println("\r\n");
        String line = reader.readLine();// line to go line by line from file
        while (line != null)// repeat till the file is read
        {
            printWriter.println(line);// print current line

            line = reader.readLine();// read next line
        }
        reader.close();// close the reader
        printWriter.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't have to use the index.length(), but I'm sure that will come in handy when it comes to bigger files. My biggest problem was I was trying to add "HTTP/...." to "\r\n" within the file itself. Doing that in the code then reading just the http within the file made this work. Thanks again!

Comment: Tested the scenario when HTTP headers appear inside the file and there's an empty line between the headers and the body - it worked fine too :)

Comment: @Msnoyce, if you think my answer has been helpful, please consider marking it as accepted :)  Thanks!

Comment: sorry. New to posting to stackoverflow. I marked it now. Also, the tip about adding the file length is coming in handy with the later part of this project, so thanks again for that!